# How do I adjust transparency on heatmap so that I can see background raster map? QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, heat-map, transparency-opacity

I have created a raster heatmap for the first time, but I can't seem to adjust the transparency settings to let me see another background OS raster map beneath it. I have attempted to swap the positions of the maps around in the layers bar but this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 'Transparency' tab in Layer properties. You can adjust transparency for the whole raster or for specific values there.

Comment: I have tried using the Transparency tab, but even set to 100% I still cannot see the background raster map beneath. Any ideas?

Comment: @BenWells, screenshots are needed.

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/QGIS4_zpsf4364681.jpg

Comment: So basically the SP12E is the OS background raster that I want to be able to see beneath the heatmap. It does not seem to make any difference what transparency settings I use

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/QGIS1_zps956d8139.jpg

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/QGIS3_zps56fdd6d1.jpg

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/QGIS2_zps884aac55.jpg

Comment: what about screenshot that demonstrate a relevant part of the rester with and without transparency options applied?

Comment: OK, sorry for the delay. This first screenshot shows the raster layer (SP12E) which is a black and white Ordnance Survey 50k map. The area that following screenshots will show is adjacent to the black arrow at top centre right of the map. The heat map data has been saved as a shapefile layer whilst the Species heat map layer is another raster layer (tif). SP12E transparency is set to 0%, whilst the species heat map transparency is at 20%.

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/Screen1_zps65fa144e.png

Comment: This next screenshot shows part of the heatmap that is positioned where the black arrow was on the previous screenshot. However, to view this, I had to deselect the SP12E layer and then select "Zoom to layer extent" on the Species heatmap properties. Transparency has not been changed. Increasing the transparency on the species heatmap merely reduces visibility of the hotspots but SP12E is not visible even at 100% transparency.

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/Screen2_zpse71d3e66.png

Comment: This shows the transparency settings for Species heatmap

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/Screen3_zpse5ab6d57.png

Comment: I am at a loss as to what is happening here. I have checked project properties to ensure each layer is using the same CRS (OSGB 1936) and "Enable on the fly CRS transformations" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem eventually. The issue wasn't transparency at all. When I zoomed right out I discovered that my heat spots were plotted at a completely different location because the x,y coordinates imported in the data table were one digit less than the coordinates used in the map projection. Another lesson learnt!